# SQL запрос while pdo

Tags: sql, pdo, while

Помогите пожалуйста, как я могу сделать вывод циклом информацию из такой таблицы:

```
id|name|connect|
1 |cat1|   0   |
2 |cat2|   1   |
3 |cat3|   2   |
4 |cat4|   3   |
5 |cat5|   4   |
6 |cat6|   5   |
7 |cat7|   6   |
8 |cat8|   7   |
9 |cat9|   8   |
10|cat10|  9   |
```

Это таблица категорий.
`cat10` является дочерней `cat9`.
Как сделать цикл до момента пока категория не будет родительской `cat1`.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что по итогу должен вывести скрипт? В какой-то структуре? Поясните фразу ``cat10 является дочерней cat9``

Comment: connect - это parent_id, только без foreign key, потому что не NULL, а 0?

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию.

Comment: Суть задачи, просчитать товары в каждой категории. И вывести последнюю ту категорию, в которой есть товары а в следующих нет. Но пока мне просто нужно цепочку вывести `cat10 подчиняется cat9` и т.д.

Comment: @Akina mysql 7.4.6

Comment: @Владислав Самохин Php? То есть надо просто выводить элементы с конца до тех пор, пока connect этого элемента не достигнет 0?

Comment: @Denis640Kb верно, pdo соединение.

Comment: *mysql 7.4.6* Нет такой версии. Смотрите лучше.

Answer (score -1):

1. Подключаемся к БД. 
   Файл `Dbase.php`

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=Base_name;host=base_ip;charset=utf8', 'BDlogin', 'BDpassword');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

2. Выводим инфо. файл `ttt.php`

```
<?php
require 'Dbase.php'; // Подключаем БД
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stackover ORDER BY id DESC"; // Запрос
$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();
$array = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Получаем все данные
if($array){
    $i = 0;
    while(isset($array[$i+1])){
        echo '<br>'.$array[$i]['name'];
        foreach ($array as $arr){
            if($array[$i]['connect'] == $arr['id']){ // Если поле connect совпадает с id другого элемента - выводим сообщение.
                echo ' является дочерней категорией '.$arr['name'];
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: а если будет сто тыщ категорий?

Answer (score -3):

Не надо читать то что пишут люди, не имеющие опыта в программировании

Файл pdo.php (возьми за правило именовать файлы только в одном регистре - избежишь множества проблем в будущем)

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$port = "3306";
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset;port=$port";
try {
     $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

Тут долго всё объяснять, проще дать [ссылку](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)

> Как сделать цикл до момента пока категория не будет родительской cat1.

**Так и сделать.** Цикл. Пока родитель не станет нулём.

```
<?php
require 'pdo.php';
$name = 'cat10';
do {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from category where name=?");
    $stmt->execute([$name]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    echo $row['name'];
} while($row['parent']);
```

Comment: Я не знаю какой будет `$name`

Comment: это ты сейчас пошутил так остроумно?